# Как вывести json ответ в php?

Tags: php, json

Я отправляю json запрос
$cardinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://lookup.binlist.net/'.$_POST['cardFrom']),true);
и получаю ответ:

```
{"number":{"length":16,"luhn":true},"scheme":"visa","type":"debit","brand":"Gold","prepaid":false,"country":{"numeric":"642","alpha2":"RO","name":"Romania","emoji":"","currency":"RON","latitude":46,"longitude":25},"bank":{"name":"ING BANK, N.V.","url":"www.ing.ro","phone":"021 402 83 91"}}
```

После я вывожу эти данные:

```
Банк: $cardinfo[bank][name]\n
Информация:\n$cardinfo[scheme]\n
$cardinfo[type]\n
$cardinfo[brand]
```

В ответ на название банка получаю значение Array[name]
остальные запросы выводятся корректно

Comment: Забавный кстати вопрос. Заставил меня на минутку задуматься :)

Comment: уже час думаю))

Comment: можно попробовать выводить как-нибудь по-другому

Comment: уже сделал)))))

Comment: кавычки еще у имен полей не забывайте писать.

Comment: они не нужны в данной ситуации

Comment: @teran ну, в том виде, в котором написано в вопросе, их как раз надо "забыть". А вот в любом другом варианте ему РНР и сам напишет, надеюсь.

Comment: в том варианте как сейчас, если автор таки поставит `{$...}` то варнинг все же получит зы: вообще не знал, что можно писать в строках без кавычек :D